# надо удалить данные с помощью spring и jdbc, из трех таблиц

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data

Задача состоит в том чтобы удалить все поля в БД по айди, а беда в том что я не знаю как это все реализовать в подобных sql запросах и как передать все это через jdbcTemplate, ну или может как то еще. Помогите пожалуйста

> String sql = "DELETE FROM contact_hobby_detail WHERE contact_id =
>   ':id'";
>
> String s = "DELETE FROM contact_tel_detail WHERE contact_id=':id'";
>
> String a = "DELETE FROM contact WHERE ID=':id'";
>
> jdbcTemplate.update("some sql query", params);

Comment: что значит *удалить все поля в БД по айди*? может речь идет о строках?

Comment: Это значит что надо удалить все энтити по любому заданному айди, в трёх таблицах, если оно существует, подобным либо другим образом используя sql